# How to redirect user to relevant subdomain

Tags: asp.net, .net, redirect, subdomain, web-hosting

I have a website. And there are multiple subdomain. for example

```
newyork.mysite.com
california.mysite.com
```

What I need is if user connect to mysite.com so based on user's location the respective subdomain is displayed in url

For example if user is from new york and that user type mysite.com then this user redirected to

```
newyork.mysite.com
```

How can I accomplish it. Should I do redirection in Global.asax?

Comment: I would call the method to do this in the load event of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it into your global.asax file by implementing your logic in the BeginRequest event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

If your logic to redirect to the appropriate subdomain requires some fancy logic, you could also implement it into the default page of your site (ie. Default.aspx page init or load event)